# Problems porting Matlab interp2 to SciPy interp2d

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm rewriting a Matlab's code in Python Language.
In Matlab code I have this function: `gt= interp2(I(:,:,i)',xi,yi,'cubic')';`, where `I` is a RGB image, `xi` and `yi` are 2D matrixes with same shape defining the x and y coordinates.
After I set `gt(isnan(gt))=0;` for the values outside the boundaries.
This function runs perfectly on Matlab.

In Python I wrote the following code: `gt=interpolate.interp2d(x,y,img.T,kind='cubic',fill_value=0)`, where `x` and `y` are the same as the `xi` and `yi` in Matlab, and img is a gray-scale image.
Anyway i get the following exception: `"Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid")
ValueError: Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid"`.
What is wrong?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your code, but in the past I've ported `interp2` to scipy as `interpolate.RectBivariateSpline` rather than `interpolate.interp2d`. But I found that instead of giving `X` and `Y` as the matrix outputs from `meshgrid`, it just takes a single row and a single column vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) you should note a few things:

1. > If x and y represent a regular grid, consider using
   >   **RectBivariateSpline**.
2. `x` and `y` should be 1D vectors unlike in Matlab and they match with Matlab's `x` and `y` and **NOT** with `xi` and `yi`. Those come later.
3. SciPy will return a function to use to interpolate later. Matlab retuns the interpolated vector immediately.

You've used it in Matlab but implicitly assuming that

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:size(I,1), 1:size(I,2))
gt= interp2(X, Y, I(:,:,i)',xi,yi,'cubic')';
```

So it's actually this `X` and `Y` that you need to pass to interpolation.interp2d and NOT `xi` and `yi`, they come later.

In SciPy you can actually skip the `meshgrid` step and just use a normal range but also it outputs a function for later rather than performing the interpolation on the spot (note there might be small errors in my definitions of `x` and `y`, I'm not that familiar with `arange`):

```
x = arange(1, img.shape[0]+1)
y = arange(1, img.shape[1]+1)
f = interpolation.interp2d(x, y, img.T)
```

and then when you want to do the interpolation:

```
gt = f(xi, yi)
```

Comment: How to use interp2 function for a closed contour?