# Unification ct scan voxel size by using interpolation in Python

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation, dicom

I have used `interp2` in Matlab, such as the following code, that is part of  @rayryeng's answer in: [Three dimensional (3D) matrix interpolation in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766557/three-dimensional-3d-matrix-interpolation-in-matlab):

```matlab
d = size(volume_image)
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:1/scaleCoeff(2):d(2), 1:1/scaleCoeff(1):d(1));
for ind = z
    %Interpolate each slice via interp2   
    M2D(:,:,ind) = interp2(volume_image(:,:,ind), X, Y);   
end
```

Example of Dimensions:

```
The image size is 512x512 and the number of slices is 133. So:
volume_image(rows, columns, slices in 3D dimenson) : 512x512x133 in 3D dimenson
X: 288x288
Y: 288x288
scaleCoeff(2): 0.5625
scaleCoeff(1): 0.5625
z = 1 up to 133 ,hence z: 1x133
ind: 1 up to 133
M2D(:,:,ind) finally is 288x288x133 in 3D dimenson
```

Aslo, Matlabs syntax for size: (rows, columns, slices in 3rd dimenson) and Python syntax for size: (slices in 3rd dim, rows, columns).
However, after convert the Matlab code to Python code occurred an error, `ValueError: Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid`:

```
for ind in range(0, len(z)+1):
    M2D[ind, :, :] = interpolate.interp2d(X, Y, volume_image[ind, :, :]) # ValueError: Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid
```

What is wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: How did you create `volume_image`? Usually, in Python, arrays are stored in C order, not F order like Matlab, so it would be `volume_image[:, :, ind]`. Also the range is wrong, you want to use `for ind in range(len(z):`.

Comment: @ Matthieu Brucher: I found out: Matlabs syntax for `size: (x = rows, y = columns, z = slices in 3D dimenson)` and Python syntax for `size: [z = slices in 3D dim, x = rows, y = columns] ` and also, the range of `for` is the same as Matlab. I edited my example in the question.

Comment: How did you read your image? You still have an error with `len(z)` and why is z not a vector but a matrix?.

Comment: @ Matthieu Brucher: I collect the images as  `volume_image[i, :, :] = dcm_image.pixel_array` in a loop.   `z` is number of slices in 3rd dimension.The error is because of `interp2d` and not `len(z)`.

Comment: You may want to use scikit.image instead. `len(z)` is an error, but I would say that the content of `volume_image` also doesn't allow a good interpolation. But we don't have its content.

Comment: In each iteration of `for` loop, the content of `volume_image` is an image with a size of 512x512, and using `ind` we can access the 133 images (in 3rd dimension).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems porting Matlab interp2 to SciPy interp2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567252/problems-porting-matlab-interp2-to-scipy-interp2d)

Comment: Have you looked at the linked post?

Comment: Yes, but the problem isn't solved yet!

Comment: So what is missing compared to the link?

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher: I have read the answers: "instead of giving `X`  and `Y` as the matrix outputs from meshgrid, it just takes a `single row` and a `single column` vector. " then I have used it but one error is found: `interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(X, Y, volume_image[ind, :, :])` is used and the error is: `ValueError: x dimension of z must have same number of elements as x`.

Comment: Try scikit.image, it's meant for interpolation of images.

Comment: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_edge_modes.html

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher: I checked [link](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_edge_modes.html) but couldn't be helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB, [`interp2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) has as arguments:

```
result = interp2(input_x, input_y, input_z, output_x, output_y)
```

You are using only the latter 3 arguments, the first two are assumed to be `input_x = 1:size(input_z,2)` and `input_y = 1:size(input_z,1)`.

In Python, [`scipy.interpolate.interp2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) is quite different: it takes the first 3 input arguments of the MATLAB function, and returns an object that you can call to get interpolated values:

```
f = scipy.interpolate.interp2(input_x, input_y, input_z)
result = f(output_x, output_y)
```

Following the example from the documentation, I get to something like this:

```
from scipy import interpolate
x = np.arange(0, volume_image.shape[2])
y = np.arange(0, volume_image.shape[1])
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, volume_image[ind, :, :])
xnew = np.arange(0, volume_image.shape[2], 1/scaleCoeff[0])
ynew = np.arange(0, volume_image.shape[1], 1/scaleCoeff[1])
M2D[ind, :, :] = f(xnew, ynew)
```

[Code not tested, please let me know if there are errors.]

Comment: There is an error: `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (288,1024) into shape (288,288)`. I want to resize an image with the size of `512x512` to `288x288`.

Comment: @eli: Maybe I misinterpreted your definition of `scaleCoeff`. Make usre that `xnew` and `ynew` each have 288 elements.

Comment: Yes, it was because of `scaleCoeff`. My problem is solved. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [`scipy.ndimage.zoom`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom). If you are interpolating from one regular grid to another, it is much faster and easier to use than `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`.

See this answer for an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16984081/1295595

You'd probably want something like:

```
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
M2D = ndimage.zoom(volume_image, (1, scaleCoeff[0], scaleCoeff[1])
```